# Stopwatch Recording to 4 decimal places

Tags: c#, time, stopwatch

I am using the system diagnostics stopwatch to time how long my function takes to run. Currently the output is `0` as it is under `1ms`. How can I record to under a millisecond to 4 decimal places?. I am aware of 'ticks', however I would prefer not to convert ticks to milliseconds for all my timings.

I am currently using the below code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
myFunction();
watch.Stop();
double elapsedTime = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;   //How to get to 4 decimal places? 
Console.WriteLine("Time " + elapsedTime );
```

Comment: _I would prefer not to convert ticks to milliseconds for all my timings_ Just, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of milliseconds you should work on `watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds`.

```
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
myFunction();
watch.Stop();
double elapsedTime = watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
Console.WriteLine("Time " + elapsedTime);
```

[image]

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Given he said he doesn't want to convert ticks to milliseconds for all timings, maybe provide an extension method that does this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

> Gets the value of the current TimeSpan structure expressed in whole
>   and fractional milliseconds.

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
for(int i = 0; i <= 100000; i++)
{
    //        
}
watch.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed (ms): {0}", watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Output will formatted like;

> Time elapsed (ms): 0.1575

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/gv7Gmz).

Comment: This answer addresses the requirement that *"I would prefer not to convert ticks to milliseconds for all my timings"*

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yeah, I notice that line after send my answer, I'm thinking another solution right now..

Answer (score 0):

In order to get **microseconds** instead of **milliseconds** you can use:

```
double elapsedMicroseconds = watch.ElapsedTicks / (TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond / 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.Format` and do

```
string s = String.Format({0:0.4F}, elapsedTime);
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedmilliseconds.aspx):

> The [ElapsedMilliseconds] property represents elapsed time rounded down to the nearest whole millisecond value. For higher precision measurements, use the Elapsed or ElapsedTicks properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio 2010 or above, I'd suggest you should stick to Performance Analysis tools that ship with VS. They'll give you ACCURATE and DETAILED results on how much a particular function and sub-functions are taking, both in terms of CPU and memory.

Comment: Is this built in to VS2010 or some kind of addon?

Comment: Built-in. Check the `Analyze` menu in VS2010.

Comment: Code Analysis can only be found in the Premium and Ultimate editions of Visual Studio 2010. Unfortunately i have professional.